# Access the filesystem as the root user

Tags: kernel, embedded, console, u-boot, squashfs

Embedded device, Linux version 2.6.26.5, U-Boot 2009.03 bootloader. ARM Linux Kernel Image on NAND flash, loading from NAND.

How to access the filesystem as the root user, and to reset the root password? Is it possible to get this by supplying `single` boot argument (single-user mode) to Linux kernel via U-boot parameters?  Or by adding `init=/bin/bash` argument to the end of the boot parameters.
The output of `bootargs` and `bootcmd` environment variables:

```
Kernel command line: console=ttyS1,115200n8 rootfstype=squashfs noalign half_image=0 verify=y Hw_Model=RZU017 Router_Mode=0
```

Comment: @roaima: after the Kernel is fully loaded, then it issues the console login prompt. (login:)

Comment: There are clearly noted that pass is not known.

Comment: If it was clear I wouldn't have had to ask what you meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct command for this board is:

```
setenv bootargs ${bootargs} single init=/bin/sh
```

(there is no bash installed)